# Override window close behavior

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pyobjc

I want to catch all tries to close some specific existing Cocoa window and add some own handler (which might indeed really close it or do something different).

I had different solutions in mind to do this. One was:

I want to replace the window close button of an existing Cocoa window at runtime with an own close widget where I can add some own code.

Right now, I have this code:

```
import objc
_NSThemeCloseWidget = objc.lookUpClass("_NSThemeCloseWidget")

def find_close_widget(window):
    contentView = window.contentView()
    grayFrame = contentView.superview()
    for i in range(len(grayFrame.subviews())):
        v = grayFrame.subviews()[i]
        if isinstance(v, _NSThemeCloseWidget):
            return v, i, grayFrame

class CustomCloseWidget(_NSThemeCloseWidget):
    pass

def replace_close_widget(window, clazz=CustomCloseWidget):
    v, i, grayFrame = find_close_widget(window)
    newv = clazz.alloc().init()
    grayFrame.subviews()[i] = newv
```

However, this doesn't seem quite right. (It crashes.)

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the NSWindowDelegate protocol e.g. windowShouldClose or windowWillClose if you want to modify closing behavior ?

Comment: I agree - that's what the delegates are for.  So you can hook into the decision making pipeline ...

Comment: I cannot set a new delegate at the point where I am needing it. However, I could hook into windowShouldClose or so. But how can I really change the behavior there then? (Not only should it not close it in some cases, it should also do some action sometimes.)

Comment: @Albert: Are you saying you already have a delegate for the window? If so, then you're practically done: All you need to do now is have that object talk to whatever object needs to control whether the window should close/respond to that action you mentioned.

Comment: @Peter: There is a delegate but it is coming from other code which I cannot change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going another route now. This is partly Chrome related but it can easily be adopted elsewhere. I wanted to catch several actions for closing the window as early as possible to avoid any other cleanups or so which resulted in the window being in a strange state.

```
def check_close_callback(obj):
    # check ...
    return True # or:
    return False

import objc
BrowserWindowController = objc.lookUpClass("BrowserWindowController")

# copied from objc.signature to avoid warning
def my_signature(signature, **kw):
    from objc._objc import selector
    kw['signature'] = signature
    def makeSignature(func):
        return selector(func, **kw)
    return makeSignature

windowWillCloseSig = "c12@0:4@8" # BrowserWindowController.windowWillClose_.signature
commandDispatchSig = "v12@0:4@8"
class BrowserWindowController(objc.Category(BrowserWindowController)):
    @my_signature(windowWillCloseSig)
    def myWindowShouldClose_(self, sender):
        print "myWindowShouldClose", self, sender
        if not check_close_callback(self): return objc.NO
        return self.myWindowShouldClose_(sender) # this is no recursion when we exchanged the methods

    @my_signature(commandDispatchSig)
    def myCommandDispatch_(self, cmd):
        try: print "myCommandDispatch_", self, cmd
        except: pass # like <type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)
        if cmd.tag() == 34015: # IDC_CLOSE_TAB
            if not check_close_callback(self): return           
        self.myCommandDispatch_(cmd)

from ctypes import *
capi = pythonapi

# id objc_getClass(const char *name)
capi.objc_getClass.restype = c_void_p
capi.objc_getClass.argtypes = [c_char_p]

# SEL sel_registerName(const char *str)
capi.sel_registerName.restype = c_void_p
capi.sel_registerName.argtypes = [c_char_p]

def capi_get_selector(name):
    return c_void_p(capi.sel_registerName(name))

# Method class_getInstanceMethod(Class aClass, SEL aSelector)
# Will also search superclass for implementations.
capi.class_getInstanceMethod.restype = c_void_p
capi.class_getInstanceMethod.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p]

# void method_exchangeImplementations(Method m1, Method m2)
capi.method_exchangeImplementations.restype = None
capi.method_exchangeImplementations.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p]

def method_exchange(className, origSelName, newSelName):
    clazz = capi.objc_getClass(className)
    origMethod = capi.class_getInstanceMethod(clazz, capi_get_selector(origSelName))
    newMethod = capi.class_getInstanceMethod(clazz, capi_get_selector(newSelName))
    capi.method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, newMethod)

def hook_into_windowShouldClose():
    method_exchange("BrowserWindowController", "windowShouldClose:", "myWindowShouldClose:")

def hook_into_commandDispatch():
    method_exchange("BrowserWindowController", "commandDispatch:", "myCommandDispatch:")
```

This code is from [here](https://github.com/albertz/ChromeWebApps) and [here](https://github.com/albertz/chromehacking).

Answer (score 1):

The close widget isn't the only way to close the window. There's a public API to obtain the widget, so you don't need to go rifling through the frame view's subviews, but that's the wrong path anyway.

The right way is to make an object to be the window's delegate, and [interfere with the window's closure](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowShouldClose%3a) there. Ideally, you should set the window's delegate in between creating the window and ordering it in.

Comment: I cannot change window's delegate in my case. I cannot assure that there is other code I have no control about which changes it back and again other code which would break because of this.